# Opción de salir de un bucle

Tags: java, eclipse

Debo hacer un bucle que permita la opción de volver a ingresar los datos después de obtener el resultado y para salir presionar 0. Estoy usando el bucle `for`. No sé si debería hacerlo con un `do/while`, pero lo he intentando con ambos y no logro que me aparezca el mensaje de que si quiero ingresar mas datos presione la opción 1 pero al hacerlo no me regresa a volver ingresar los datos.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Que peso soporta la tela de araña? :");
    int peso = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Peso del elefante numero 1: ");
    int elefante1 = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Peso del elefante numero 2: ");
    int elefante2 = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Peso del elefante numero 3: ");
    int elefante3 = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Peso del elefante numero 4: ");
    int elefante4 = sc.nextInt();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < peso; i++) {
       
        if(peso < elefante1 + elefante2 + elefante3 + elefante4) {
            System.out.println("Y se rompió!");
            break;
        }
        if(peso > elefante1 + elefante2 + elefante3 + elefante4) {
            System.out.println("La tela de araña aun aguanta!");
            break;
        }                 
    }
    System.out.println("Si desea volver a consultar la tela de araña presione 1");
    int consultar = sc.nextInt();
       
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo lo has hecho con un for o con un do/while que dices que no te funciona? Publica el código de lo que has intentado para hacer el bucle y cómo has intentado terminarlo cuando pulsa el 0 y trataremos de buscar una solución.

Comment: El bucle for que estas usando no hace nada. Piensa que lo que quieres es que vuelva a preguntarte los datos si se pulsa 1. Para ello tendrás que meter dentro del bucle el código que quieres que se repita. Una pista sobre el bucle a utilizar, repasa el bucle `while` y el `do/while` y considera cuándo quieres que se repita.

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto el código modificado con lo que entiendo que necesitas, pruebalo y me comentas.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Que peso soporta la tela de araña? :");
        int peso = sc.nextInt();
        int peso_actual = 0;
        boolean loop = true;
        while(loop){
            System.out.println("Peso del elefante numero 1: ");
            int elefante1 = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Peso del elefante numero 2: ");
            int elefante2 = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Peso del elefante numero 3: ");
            int elefante3 = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Peso del elefante numero 4: ");
            int elefante4 = sc.nextInt();
            
            peso_actual = peso_actual + elefante1 + elefante2 + elefante3 + elefante4;
            if(peso < peso_actual) {
                System.out.println("Y se rompió!, Peso: " + peso_actual);
                break;
            }
            if(peso > peso_actual) {
                System.out.println("La tela de araña aun aguanta!, peso: "+peso_actual+" \n");
            }   
            
            System.out.println("Si desea volver a consultar la tela de araña presione 1 \n");
            int consultar = sc.nextInt();
            if(consultar != 1){
                break;
            }
            
        }
```

1. Lo ideal es que puedas controlar el loop con un condicional, para este caso puedes utilizar un while (es más fácil hacer este tipo lógica)
2. Dentro del loop vas sumando el peso de los elefantes hasta llegar al peso máximo, las condiciones las tienes bien.
3. utilizando el break puedes para bruscamente un while o utilizando el mismo booleano loop, cuando el usuario presione 1 puedes cambiar la variable con false.

Espero se entienda y te sirva.
Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias diego, estoy empezando con esto y creo que tampoco supe explicarlo, lo he entendido y me ha servido, un saludo.